# Is it possible to install Android app (APK) via MTP mode?

Tags: android, linux, mtp

Is it possible to install an android application via MTP mode under Linux (Ubuntu)?

Comment: is not possible, MTP allows for mount filesystem or transfer files to or from a phone. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol.